# Trip schema for ferry travel

Tags: schema.org

I'm looking for the most appropriate schema markup for the info in the image for ferry journeys.

[image: example of info I need to markup]

I am looking at either [`Trip`](https://schema.org/Trip) schema or [`Table`](https://schema.org/Table) schema.

But I'm struggling to workout how to implement `Trip` schema, can anyone advise? Just understanding which bits to include, so with `Trip` schema, I don't have `hasPart`, `isPartOf` or `itinerary`. Am I making this difficult for myself by trying to use a schema which doesn't fit my needs exactly?

Or is this the wrong one to go with altogether?

Answer (score 1):

I might consider [schema:Service](https://schema.org/Service) since you're offering a service so regular that it is available basically every day.

Service will let you specify `areaServed`, `offers`, and `provider`. The `offers` property is where you can specify pricing.

Comment: Thank you - The issue with this table is we can't easily bring in prices due to the technical set up & how often then change. So we've just decided we'll include a booking button & this will go through to the booking panel.

Comment: @Becky You can specify offers without specifying pricing. And booking buttons are orthogonal to structured data, they shouldn't change your structured data strategy.